# Паттерн для инициализации состояния класса вне конструктора

Tags: java, c#, ооп, шаблоны-проектирования

Допустим есть класс, который записывает свое состояние на диск, а при инициализации подгружает обратно. Логично делать это в конструкторе. Но с точки зрения unit тестов, это криво. Если я выношу это в метод initialize, то я обязываю внешний код дергать еще и его, потом это плодит разные статусы initializing итд итп.

Правильно ли я понимаю, что хорошим дизайном будет следующее:

- какая-то фабрика, которая отвечает за создание и инициализацию класса
- объект "LastStateInfo"
- в класс добавляется дополнительный конструктор, который принимает LastStateInfo

Есть ли какие-то типовые подходы? Как это называется? Как это можно нагуглить?

Comment: Одним из подходов является паттерн [Хранитель](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Хранитель_(шаблон_проектирования)) (Memento).

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov оформили бы ответом с минимальным примером кода.

Comment: *"Как это можно нагуглить?"* -- 1) купить или скачать GoF, 2) прочитать, 3) при возникновении вопросов обращаться к списку шаблонов в книге и быстро находить нужный.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для сохранения состояния есть паттерн Хранитель (Momento).
Сам класс не должен реализовывать алгоритм сохранения/восстановления состояния (обратное нарушает принципы SOLID, а именно SRP). Тогда и проблем с юнит-тестами не будет. Вместо зависимостей подсуните моки/стабы.